# avcodec_find_decoder for FFMpeg 2.1 is not working with Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

I ported FFMpeg 2.1 to Android with NDK and I wrote a JNI function to initialize a video.

Here is the code of this C function :

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_media_ffmpeg_FFMpeg_naInit(JNIEnv *pEnv, jobject pObj, jstring pfilename) {
    gVideoFileName = (char *) (*pEnv)->GetStringUTFChars(pEnv, pfilename, NULL);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "Init %s\n", gVideoFileName);

    avcodec_register_all();
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "avcodec_register_all\n");

    av_register_all();
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "av_register_all\n");

    VideoState *vs;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "VideoState var\n");

    vs = malloc(sizeof (VideoState));
    memset(vs, 0, sizeof(VideoState));
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "malloc\n");

    gvs = vs;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "VideoState\n");

    //open the video file
    avformat_open_input(&vs->pFormatCtx, gVideoFileName, NULL, NULL);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "open_input\n");

    //retrieve stream info
    avformat_find_stream_info(vs->pFormatCtx, NULL);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "find_stream_info\n");

    //find the video stream
    AVCodecContext *pcodecctx;
    //find the first video stream
    vs->videoStreamIdx = -1;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "before loop\n");

    AVCodec *pcodec;

    vs->videoStreamIdx =  av_find_best_stream(vs->pFormatCtx, AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO, -1, -1, &pcodec, 0);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "after loop. %d\n", vs->videoStreamIdx);

    //get the decoder from the video stream
    pcodecctx = vs->pFormatCtx->streams[vs->videoStreamIdx]->codec;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "stream selected %d, %d\n", pcodecctx != NULL ? 1 : 0, pcodecctx->codec_id);

    pcodec = avcodec_find_decoder(pcodecctx->codec_id);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "find_decoder\n");

    //open the codec
    avcodec_open2(pcodecctx, pcodec, NULL);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, TAG, "open2\n");

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute this function from my Java code the log `find_decoder` (after the call to the function `avcodec_find_decoder`) is never displayed.

Everything is correct : pointers have correct values and `pcodecctx->codec_id` has a value equal to **28**.
But when `avcodec_find_decoder` there is nothing more, like a crash and I have no more log.

Did I do something wrong when using and initializing FFMpeg ?

PS : before that instead of a call to `malloc`, then `memset` I had a call to `av_mallocz` but I also had a crash at this point, and replacing this call by `malloc` and `memset` fixed the crash.

**EDIT**

I built `FFMpeg` using this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/Users/me/android-ndk
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-8/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
 --prefix=$PREFIX \
 --disable-shared \
 --enable-static \
 --disable-doc \
 --disable-ffmpeg \
 --disable-ffplay \
 --disable-ffprobe \
 --disable-ffserver \
 --disable-avdevice \
 --disable-doc \
 --disable-symver \
 --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
 --target-os=linux \
 --arch=arm \
 --enable-cross-compile \
 --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
 --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
 --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
 $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU 
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is the output for the configuration of the build of the library

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
install prefix            /Users/fabienhenon/android-ndk/sources/ffmpeg/android/arm
source path               .
C compiler                /Users/fabienhenon/android-ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
C library                 bionic
host C compiler           gcc
host C library            
ARCH                      arm (armv5te)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     yes
ARMv5TE enabled           yes
ARMv6 enabled             yes
ARMv6T2 enabled           yes
VFP enabled               yes
NEON enabled              yes
THUMB enabled             no
debug symbols             yes
strip symbols             yes
optimize for size         no
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    no
new filter support        yes
network support           yes
threading support         pthreads
safe bitstream reader     yes
SDL support               no
opencl enabled            no
libzvbi enabled           no
texi2html enabled         no
perl enabled              yes
pod2man enabled           yes
makeinfo enabled          yes

External libraries:
zlib

Enabled decoders:
aac         bmp         iac
aac_latm        bmv_audio       idcin
aasc            bmv_video       idf
ac3         brender_pix     iff_byterun1
adpcm_4xm       c93         iff_ilbm
adpcm_adx       cavs            imc
adpcm_afc       cdgraphics      indeo2
adpcm_ct        cdxl            indeo3
adpcm_dtk       cinepak         indeo4
adpcm_ea        cljr            indeo5
adpcm_ea_maxis_xa   cllc            interplay_dpcm
adpcm_ea_r1     comfortnoise        interplay_video
adpcm_ea_r2     cook            jacosub
adpcm_ea_r3     cpia            jpeg2000
adpcm_ea_xas        cscd            jpegls
adpcm_g722      cyuv            jv
adpcm_g726      dca         kgv1
adpcm_g726le        dfa         kmvc
adpcm_ima_amv       dirac           lagarith
adpcm_ima_apc       dnxhd           loco
adpcm_ima_dk3       dpx         mace3
adpcm_ima_dk4       dsicinaudio     mace6
adpcm_ima_ea_eacs   dsicinvideo     mdec
adpcm_ima_ea_sead   dvbsub          metasound
adpcm_ima_iss       dvdsub          microdvd
adpcm_ima_oki       dvvideo         mimic
adpcm_ima_qt        dxa         mjpeg
adpcm_ima_rad       dxtory          mjpegb
adpcm_ima_smjpeg    eac3            mlp
adpcm_ima_wav       eacmv           mmvideo
adpcm_ima_ws        eamad           motionpixels
adpcm_ms        eatgq           movtext
adpcm_sbpro_2       eatgv           mp1
adpcm_sbpro_3       eatqi           mp1float
adpcm_sbpro_4       eightbps        mp2
adpcm_swf       eightsvx_exp        mp2float
adpcm_thp       eightsvx_fib        mp3
adpcm_xa        escape124       mp3adu
adpcm_yamaha        escape130       mp3adufloat
aic         evrc            mp3float
alac            exr         mp3on4
als         ffv1            mp3on4float
amrnb           ffvhuff         mpc7
amrwb           ffwavesynth     mpc8
amv         flac            mpeg1video
anm         flashsv         mpeg2video
ansi            flashsv2        mpeg4
ape         flic            mpegvideo
ass         flv         mpl2
asv1            fourxm          msa1
asv2            fraps           msmpeg4v1
atrac1          frwu            msmpeg4v2
atrac3          g2m         msmpeg4v3
aura            g723_1          msrle
aura2           g729            mss1
avrn            gif         mss2
avrp            gsm         msvideo1
avs         gsm_ms          mszh
avui            h261            mts2
ayuv            h263            mvc1
bethsoftvid     h263i           mvc2
bfi         h263p           mxpeg
bink            h264            nellymoser
binkaudio_dct       hevc            nuv
binkaudio_rdft      hnm4_video      paf_audio
bintext         huffyuv         paf_video
pam         realtext        v308
pbm         rl2         v408
pcm_alaw        roq         v410
pcm_bluray      roq_dpcm        vb
pcm_dvd         rpza            vble
pcm_f32be       rv10            vc1
pcm_f32le       rv20            vc1image
pcm_f64be       rv30            vcr1
pcm_f64le       rv40            vima
pcm_lxf         s302m           vmdaudio
pcm_mulaw       sami            vmdvideo
pcm_s16be       sanm            vmnc
pcm_s16be_planar    sgi         vorbis
pcm_s16le       sgirle          vp3
pcm_s16le_planar    shorten         vp5
pcm_s24be       sipr            vp6
pcm_s24daud     smackaud        vp6a
pcm_s24le       smacker         vp6f
pcm_s24le_planar    smc         vp8
pcm_s32be       smvjpeg         vp9
pcm_s32le       snow            vplayer
pcm_s32le_planar    sol_dpcm        vqa
pcm_s8          sonic           wavpack
pcm_s8_planar       sp5x            webp
pcm_u16be       srt         webvtt
pcm_u16le       ssa         wmalossless
pcm_u24be       subrip          wmapro
pcm_u24le       subviewer       wmav1
pcm_u32be       subviewer1      wmav2
pcm_u32le       sunrast         wmavoice
pcm_u8          svq1            wmv1
pcm_zork        svq3            wmv2
pcx         tak         wmv3
pgm         targa           wmv3image
pgmyuv          targa_y216      wnv1
pgssub          text            ws_snd1
pictor          theora          xan_dpcm
pjs         thp         xan_wc3
png         tiertexseqvideo     xan_wc4
ppm         tiff            xbin
prores          tmv         xbm
prores_lgpl     truehd          xface
ptx         truemotion1     xl
qcelp           truemotion2     xsub
qdm2            truespeech      xwd
qdraw           tscc            y41p
qpeg            tscc2           yop
qtrle           tta         yuv4
r10k            twinvq          zero12v
r210            txd         zerocodec
ra_144          ulti            zlib
ra_288          utvideo         zmbv
ralf            v210
rawvideo        v210x

Enabled encoders:
a64multi        ljpeg           prores
a64multi5       mjpeg           prores_aw
aac         movtext         prores_ks
ac3         mp2         qtrle
ac3_fixed       mp2fixed        r10k
adpcm_adx       mpeg1video      r210
adpcm_g722      mpeg2video      ra_144
adpcm_g726      mpeg4           rawvideo
adpcm_ima_qt        msmpeg4v2       roq
adpcm_ima_wav       msmpeg4v3       roq_dpcm
adpcm_ms        msvideo1        rv10
adpcm_swf       nellymoser      rv20
adpcm_yamaha        pam         s302m
alac            pbm         sgi
amv         pcm_alaw        snow
ass         pcm_f32be       sonic
asv1            pcm_f32le       sonic_ls
asv2            pcm_f64be       srt
avrp            pcm_f64le       ssa
avui            pcm_mulaw       subrip
ayuv            pcm_s16be       sunrast
bmp         pcm_s16be_planar    svq1
cljr            pcm_s16le       targa
comfortnoise        pcm_s16le_planar    tiff
dca         pcm_s24be       tta
dnxhd           pcm_s24daud     utvideo
dpx         pcm_s24le       v210
dvbsub          pcm_s24le_planar    v308
dvdsub          pcm_s32be       v408
dvvideo         pcm_s32le       v410
eac3            pcm_s32le_planar    vorbis
ffv1            pcm_s8          wavpack
ffvhuff         pcm_s8_planar       wmav1
flac            pcm_u16be       wmav2
flashsv         pcm_u16le       wmv1
flashsv2        pcm_u24be       wmv2
flv         pcm_u24le       xbm
g723_1          pcm_u32be       xface
gif         pcm_u32le       xsub
h261            pcm_u8          xwd
h263            pcx         y41p
h263p           pgm         yuv4
huffyuv         pgmyuv          zlib
jpeg2000        png         zmbv
jpegls          ppm

Enabled hwaccels:

Enabled parsers:
aac         dvd_nav         mpegvideo
aac_latm        dvdsub          png
ac3         flac            pnm
adx         gsm         rv30
bmp         h261            rv40
cavsvideo       h263            tak
cook            h264            vc1
dca         hevc            vorbis
dirac           mjpeg           vp3
dnxhd           mlp         vp8
dpx         mpeg4video      vp9
dvbsub          mpegaudio

Enabled demuxers:
aac         hevc            pcm_s32le
ac3         hls         pcm_s8
act         hnm         pcm_u16be
adf         ico         pcm_u16le
adp         idcin           pcm_u24be
adx         idf         pcm_u24le
aea         iff         pcm_u32be
afc         ilbc            pcm_u32le
aiff            image2          pcm_u8
amr         image2pipe      pjs
anm         ingenient       pmp
apc         ipmovie         pva
ape         ircam           pvf
aqtitle         iss         qcp
asf         iv8         r3d
ass         ivf         rawvideo
ast         jacosub         realtext
au          jv          redspark
avi         latm            rl2
avr         lmlm4           rm
avs         loas            roq
bethsoftvid     lvf         rpl
bfi         lxf         rsd
bink            m4v         rso
bintext         matroska        rtp
bit         mgsts           rtsp
bmv         microdvd        sami
boa         mjpeg           sap
brstm           mlp         sbg
c93         mm          sdp
caf         mmf         segafilm
cavsvideo       mov         shorten
cdg         mp3         siff
cdxl            mpc         smacker
concat          mpc8            smjpeg
data            mpegps          smush
daud            mpegts          sol
dfa         mpegtsraw       sox
dirac           mpegvideo       spdif
dnxhd           mpl2            srt
dsicin          mpsub           str
dts         msnwc_tcp       subviewer
dtshd           mtv         subviewer1
dv          mv          swf
dxa         mvi         tak
ea          mxf         tedcaptions
ea_cdata        mxg         thp
eac3            nc          tiertexseq
epaf            nistsphere      tmv
ffm         nsv         truehd
ffmetadata      nut         tta
filmstrip       nuv         tty
flac            ogg         txd
flic            oma         vc1
flv         paf         vc1t
fourxm          pcm_alaw        vivo
frm         pcm_f32be       vmd
g722            pcm_f32le       vobsub
g723_1          pcm_f64be       voc
g729            pcm_f64le       vplayer
gif         pcm_mulaw       vqf
gsm         pcm_s16be       w64
gxf         pcm_s16le       wav
h261            pcm_s24be       wc3
h263            pcm_s24le       webvtt
h264            pcm_s32be       wsaud
wsvqa           xa          xwma
wtv         xbin            yop
wv          xmv         yuv4mpegpipe

Enabled muxers:
a64         image2pipe      pcm_s24be
ac3         ipod            pcm_s24le
adts            ircam           pcm_s32be
adx         ismv            pcm_s32le
aiff            ivf         pcm_s8
amr         jacosub         pcm_u16be
asf         latm            pcm_u16le
asf_stream      m4v         pcm_u24be
ass         matroska        pcm_u24le
ast         matroska_audio      pcm_u32be
au          md5         pcm_u32le
avi         microdvd        pcm_u8
avm2            mjpeg           psp
bit         mkvtimestamp_v2     rawvideo
caf         mlp         rm
cavsvideo       mmf         roq
crc         mov         rso
data            mp2         rtp
daud            mp3         rtsp
dirac           mp4         sap
dnxhd           mpeg1system     segment
dts         mpeg1vcd        smjpeg
dv          mpeg1video      smoothstreaming
eac3            mpeg2dvd        sox
f4v         mpeg2svcd       spdif
ffm         mpeg2video      speex
ffmetadata      mpeg2vob        srt
filmstrip       mpegts          stream_segment
flac            mpjpeg          swf
flv         mxf         tee
framecrc        mxf_d10         tg2
framemd5        null            tgp
g722            nut         truehd
g723_1          ogg         vc1
gif         oma         vc1t
gxf         opus            voc
h261            pcm_alaw        w64
h263            pcm_f32be       wav
h264            pcm_f32le       webm
hds         pcm_f64be       webvtt
hls         pcm_f64le       wtv
ico         pcm_mulaw       wv
ilbc            pcm_s16be       yuv4mpegpipe
image2          pcm_s16le

Enabled protocols:
cache           hls         rtmpt
concat          http            rtp
crypto          httpproxy       srtp
data            md5         tcp
ffrtmphttp      mmsh            udp
file            mmst            unix
ftp         pipe
gopher          rtmp

Enabled filters:
aconvert        colorchannelmixer   null
adelay          compand         nullsink
aecho           concat          nullsrc
aeval           copy            overlay
aevalsrc        crop            pad
afade           curves          pan
aformat         dctdnoiz        perms
ainterleave     decimate        pixdesctest
allpass         deshake         psnr
alphaextract        drawbox         removelogo
alphamerge      drawgrid        replaygain
amerge          earwax          rgbtestsrc
amix            edgedetect      rotate
amovie          elbg            scale
anull           equalizer       select
anullsink       extractplanes       sendcmd
anullsrc        fade            separatefields
apad            field           setdar
aperms          fieldmatch      setfield
aphaser         fieldorder      setpts
aresample       format          setsar
aselect         fps         settb
asendcmd        framestep       showinfo
asetnsamples        gradfun         showspectrum
asetpts         haldclut        showwaves
asetrate        haldclutsrc     silencedetect
asettb          hflip           sine
ashowinfo       highpass        smptebars
asplit          histogram       smptehdbars
astats          hue         split
astreamsync     idet            swapuv
atempo          il          telecine
atrim           interleave      testsrc
avectorscope        join            thumbnail
bandpass        life            tile
bandreject      lowpass         transpose
bass            lut         treble
bbox            lut3d           trim
biquad          lutrgb          unsharp
blackdetect     lutyuv          vflip
blend           mandelbrot      vignette
cellauto        mergeplanes     volume
channelmap      movie           volumedetect
channelsplit        negate          w3fdif
color           noformat
colorbalance        noise

Enabled bsfs:
aac_adtstoasc       imx_dump_header     mp3_header_decompress
chomp           mjpeg2jpeg      noise
dump_extradata      mjpega_dump_header  remove_extradata
h264_mp4toannexb    mov2textsub     text2movsub

Enabled indevs:
dv1394          lavfi
fbdev           v4l2

Enabled outdevs:
fbdev           v4l2

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later
```

Comment: Do you have any error handling in your code? You seem not to check any return values at all.

Comment: I've just checked the errors and no function is returning an error code (all return values are >= 0)

Comment: How did you build your ffmpeg, specifically - the avcodec library? Which codecs did you enable? **28** is h264, make sure that this decoder is supported in your configuration.

Comment: @AlexCohn I edited my question and added the script I used to build FFMpeg. How can I know if this decoder is supported in my configuration?

Comment: h264 is likely not supported in your configuration since you did not specify --enable-gpl and as far as I know this library is GPL. Could you run just the configure part and check the output? It lists the codecs which are enabled.

Comment: @GeorgeY. I added the output of the configure in my question. The h264 decoder seems to be available even without the --enable-gpl

Comment: Anything in the logcat? Could you compile it as a C executable and run it on the device with the command-line argument? Maybe you're running out of memory and get killed.

Comment: @GeorgeY. Nothing in the log, the code crashes as the log just after the function is not displayed. However, the application itself doesn't crash as it is displaying the previous activity (but the activity executing the ffmpeg code is not displayed). How can I run it as C executable on the device ? I don't think I'm running out of memory, the application is very simple (just a file explorer and a view to get information about the video selected)

Comment: If previous activity pops up, it looks like your application actually crashed, and the system restarted it. Add a main() function into your executable, and compile it as application. Regarding the memory, what is the resolution of the video you're playing? 1080p a single decoded frame is around 6Mb in RGB8.

Comment: And please make sure vs->videoStreamIdx is not -1.

Comment: vs->videoStreamIdx = 1 . I tried with a low quality video (360p) but it's still crashing :(